# Let $f: R \to R$ be a differentiable function suppose $f(0) = 1$ and $f'(x) ≤5$ for all $x \in (0,7)$ then find the possible values of $f(2)$.

Tags: calculus

Let $f: R \to R$ be a differentiable function suppose $f(0) = 1$ and $f'(x) ≤5$ for all $x \in (0,7)$ then find the possible values of $f(2)$.

I don't know how to start. Its slope is less than $5$ for all $x$ in $(0,7)$.
How can I use this information$?$

Comment: $f(x) = x  + K$ satisfies the conditions for arbitrary $K$. So $f(2)$ can be anything.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $f(0)=1$?

Comment: May be there is a misprint in book, since options for this problem doesn't include the whole $R$.

Comment: What will be the difference if there is $f(0) = 1?$

Comment: Recall that, for a differentiable function $f$ over $I$, a subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$, we have: $|f(x)-f(y)| \le \sup_{t \in [x,y]} |f'(t)| |x-y|$, and the inequality is sharp for linear functions.

Comment: For instance: if $f(0)=1$, can $f(2)$ be equal to $100$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is supposed to say $f(0)=1$, not $f'(0)=1$. By the mean value theorem, there is some $c\in(0,2)$ such that

$$f'(c)=\frac{f(2)-f(0)}2$$

We know $f'(x)\le5$ for all $0<x<7$, so

$$5\ge\frac{f(2)-f(0)}2\implies f(2)\le f(0)+10=11$$